# PDF Heat equation with displacement

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> I got the following problem
>   \begin{align*}
>     u_t'-u_{xx}''&=0 \quad && 0<x<\pi,\,\,t>0\\
>     u(x,0)&=f(x), \quad && 0<x<\pi,\\
>     u(0,t)&=0, \quad && 0<x<\pi\\
>     u(\pi,t)&=1,\quad && t>0
> \end{align*}
>   Find  $\displaystyle\lim_{t \to \infty} u(x,t)$

and I have changed $u(x,t)$ to $v(x,t)=f(x)-x/\pi$

I am now stuck with
$v(x,t)= \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty K_ne^{-n^2t}\sin(nx)$
and
 $b_n=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \left( f(x)-\frac{x}{\pi}\right)\sin(nx)dx$,
I have tried to solve the integral for $b$,
and I can not see the answer.

Comment: If you know what f(x) is then use integration by parts.

Comment: f(x) is not known

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it. Your formula for $v$ is not quite right, it should be $v(x,t)=u(x,t) - x/\pi$. Now it doesn't matter what the $b_n$ are (which are $K_n$ in your other formula). Try showing that $\lim_{t\to \infty} v(x,t) = 0$.

Comment: Since I am looking for the limit of t- x doesn't matter, but before that, shall I  be using the this constraint $v(x,0)=f(x)-\frac{x}{\pi}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n sin(nx)$, $Rightarrow f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n sin(nx)+\frac{x}{\pi}$. I think the answer might look like $S(x)=\pi/2+ \sum ...$ where the sum includes $ K_ne^{-n^2t}$, hence it will go to zero

Comment: It doesn't matter what the coefficients are, since the $e^{-n^2t}$ term causes $v(x,t)$ to converge to zero as $t\to \infty$. Just rearrange the formula $v(x,t) = u(x,t) - x/\pi$ to get the corresponding limit for $u(x,t)$. The point is that the limit $\lim_{t\to \infty} u(x,t) $ is completely independent of the initial condition $f(x)$. The limit is a stationary point for the PDE, that is, you can also find the limit by setting $u_t=0$ and solving $u_{xx}=0$ subject to your boundary conditions (though this is not rigorous like the Fourier series method).

Comment: I should add that $x$ does matter a great deal! The limit $\lim_{t\to \infty} u(x,t)$ will be a function of $x$.

Comment: Where does the $2/\pi$ come from. I can clearly see that as t goes to inf, the ê term will go to zero.

Comment: Which $2/\pi$ are you referring to? The one in the formula for $b_n$? This is just the formula for the Fourier sine series coefficients.

Comment: I think you are overthinking the problem. Remember $b_n$ doesn't matter for computing the limit. Just write $$u(x,t) = v(x,t) + \pi/x$$ and use what you know about the limit of $v(x,t)$....

Comment: Then I get $u(x,t)= \frac{x}{\pi}+0$ as $v(x,t)=0$ as the answer